# How to use include? method in ruby

Tags: ruby

```
vowels = "aeiou"
"hello".include?(vowels) # ==> false
```

but if I add `!` to the statement it works fine:

```
!("hello".include?(vowels) # ==> true
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read "[ask]" and its linked pages.

Comment: Welcome James. My big tip for using stackoverflow, is if I get stuck, I often add a question here with the plan to leave it overnight and see what answers I get. I also find it useful to gather my thoughts. Keep asking on here and it'll definitley help you grow as a developer.

Comment: Hey @JamesTheGuy if you're happy with one of the answers please make sure you accept an answer. It makes it worth if for those that offer assistance. If it's not answered yet, comment here and we'll help you further.

Comment: @JamesTheGuy Poke. Pls review and accept an answer.

Answer (score 3):

`.include?` assesses the provided string as a whole word, so what your method says is, 'does "hello" include the whole *sub-word* "aieou" as part of it.' This is why it's false in the first instance, as your string "hello" does not include the *word* "aeiou".

Try this and you'll get true:

```
vowels = "llo"
"hello".include?(vowels) # ==> true
```

Secondly, you're misreading what the bang ("`!`") is doing. It's not making your method work, all it does is reverse the result, so when a bang is added, any true statement becomes false and any false statement when a bang is added becomes true.

Try these:

```
> true
> !true
> false
> !false
```

You can prove it to yourself with this code:

```
vowels = "llo"
!"hello".include?(vowels) # ==> false
```

One good place to play with small Ruby logic questions is with IRB or in Rails projects with `rails console`, which extends IRB. Open the terminal/commmand prompt on your computer and type `irb` to bring up a Ruby prompt (you likley knew this, I'm just sharing it in case it helps).

You want to cycle through each of your vowels and check each individually to see if it's included, and if it is, update the result to true.

The takeaway is that when there is a collection of things to go through, you'll usually want to cycle through them using `each`, assessing one at a time.

```
vowels = "aeiou"
result = false
vowels.each_char do |char| 
  result = true if "hello".include?(char) 
end
puts result
```

There are shorter ways to do this, but this is clean, simple and easy to understand, which happens to be a good measure of good code also.

Comment: Elegant code is not necessarily the shortest or most cryptic. In the old days, when writing assembler and C we'd count clock cycles and instructions emitted. Now, given the state of compilers and interpreters, it doesn't pay off as the tools are often smarter than we are and optimize the code for us. We can actually make the code run more slowly if we get too fancy with our assumed improvements. That's why premature optimizing is a bad thing - if we don't know exactly what's wrong we can make it worse.

Comment: `vowels.each_char.any? {|char| "hello".include?(char) }`.

Answer (score 1):

Evolve already explained in his answer why your version with `include?` doesn't work.

A method to check if a string contains at least one vocal might look like this in Ruby:

```
"hello".match?(/[aeiou]/i)
#=> true
"hxllx".match?(/[aeiou]/i)
#=> false
```

[`match?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#method-i-match-3F) takes a regexp and returns `true` when the string matches the pattern. `/[aeiou]/i` is a regular expression that matches when any of (`[...]`) the chars in the list `aeiou` are found in the string at least once. The `i` at the end makes the whole expresion as case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to explain how `!` (`not`) works:

```
true    # => true
false   # => false

!true   # => false
!false  # => true

!!true  # => true
!!false # => false
```

Remember that in Ruby, `nil` and `false` are false, everything else is true. Other languages might treat 0 as false also, and that can trip up people just learning Ruby:

```
foo = nil   # => nil
bar = 0     # => 0
baz = 1     # => 1

!foo = nil  # => true
!bar = 0    # => false
!baz = 1    # => false

!!foo = nil # => false
!!bar = 0   # => true
!!baz = 1   # => true
```

And `not` is the long form of `!`:

```
!true     # => false
not true  # => false
!false    # => true
not false # => true
```

You'll often see `!!` used to convert a value to its true/false equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

As @Evolve already said, `x.include?(y)` tests whether y is a substring of x. You want to know, whether x ('hello') includes at least one character from y ('vowels'). This can be done by `x.split(//).any? {|c| y.include?(c)}`. The `split(//)` turns the string into an array of characters, and the `any?` tests whether at least one array element fulfills the property specified in the code block.